# Laravel Join query Not work properly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am trying to get a list of users with a join query, but its not working properly. I would like to retrieve all the users except the current user_id. I pass in a user_id to exclude but the results return all users and it should have a list of all users except the current user_id.

It also returns a row id value from the preferences table and not the user table.

Here is my query.

```
$query = DB::table('users')
           ->join('preferences', function($join) use($results) {
              $join->on('users.id', '=', 'preferences.UserId') 
                ->where('preferences.ClassIdFrom', '>=', $results->ClassIdFrom)
                ->where('preferences.ClassIdTo', '<=', $results->ClassIdTo);
         })
           ->where('users.id', '!=',$UserId)
           ->whereNotIn('users.id', $mid_query)
           ->whereNotIn('users.id', $last_query);

$result = $query->get();
```

If I run the query with a user_id of 22 the result should not include this user so this does not work.

```
->where('users.id', '!=',$UserId)
```

Again, the result returns all of the columns from the user table correctly except the that the id column value is coming from the preferences table.

i think after join

```
                    ->where('users.id', '!=',$UserId)
                    ->whereNotIn('users.id', $mid_query)
                    ->whereNotIn('users.id', $last_query);
```

both three not work

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify the fields to select, you will perform a `select *`. When you do this, if multiple tables have the same field name (e.g. `id`), the ultimate value retrieved will be from the last table with the field. In this case, the `preferences` table comes after the `users` table, so any fields with the same name in both tables will end up with the data from the `preferences` table.

The quick fix would be to specify your select statement:

```
$query = DB::table('users')
    ->join('preferences', function($join) use($results) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'preferences.UserId') 
            ->where('preferences.ClassIdFrom', '>=', $results->ClassIdFrom)
            ->where('preferences.ClassIdTo', '<=', $results->ClassIdTo);
    })
    ->where('users.id', '!=',$UserId)
    ->whereNotIn('users.id', $mid_query)
    ->whereNotIn('users.id', $last_query)
    ->select('users.*');
```

**Extra**

If you were to setup your Eloquent models and relationships, you could also perform this query with the Eloquent ORM.

```
$users = User::whereHas('preferences', function($query) use ($results) {
    $query->where('ClassIdFrom', '>=', $results->ClassIdFrom)
        ->where('ClassIdTo', '<=', $results->ClassIdTo);
})
    ->where('id', '!=',$UserId)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $mid_query)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $last_query)
    ->get();
```

Additionally, you could clean up your where's a little bit:

```
$ids = array_merge(array($UserId), $mid_query, $last_query);
$users = User::whereHas('preferences', function($query) use ($results) {
    $query->where('ClassIdFrom', '>=', $results->ClassIdFrom)
        ->where('ClassIdTo', '<=', $results->ClassIdTo);
})
    ->whereNotIn('id', $ids)
    ->get();
```